# Java TimeZone with custom ID doesn't take into account Daylight Saving Time

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, dst

I just want to share my experience about Java TimeZone. Here was the problem:
The `inDaylightTime(Date date)` function of timezone always returns 0, regardless of date. Consistently `getDSTSavings()` also returns 0.
here is the snippet of code to create timezone:

```
Timezone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DST in a timezone object created with an id like `"UTC+1:00"` (or "GMT+1:00") will be different with a timezone object created with corresponding string `"Europe/Berlin"`, so if DST is important to your application, always use full string id's instead of corresponding time offset.
So changing timezone definition to:

```
Timezone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 1):

No, `TimeZone` API figures out day light savings. You are using a custom time zone ID.

From the Documentation of TimeZone API

> No daylight saving time transition schedule can be specified with a custom time zone ID

So, you need to specify the time zone ID available to get day light savings

> Typically, you get a TimeZone using getDefault which creates a TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running. For example, for a program running in Japan, getDefault creates a TimeZone object based on Japanese Standard Time.You can also get a TimeZone using getTimeZone along with a time zone ID. For instance, the time zone ID for the U.S. Pacific Time zone is "America/Los_Angeles". So, you can get a U.S. Pacific Time TimeZone object with:

Use the time zone ID, this will take care of day light savings in that particular zone

```
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: You are right about the **custom TimeZone**. But in real world, _time difference description_ and _Olson id_ are used interchangeably (for example in windows clock). So one may doesn't notice documentation carefully and consider both representations of timezone **equal** (as I did).
I intentionally made topic of question as it is, because if someone makes the mistake I did, they will see the problem like it. So you are right and there is nothing buggy or something with TimeZone API. Maybe I should change title of question.

Comment: Plus, getDefault() doesn't get the proper timezone (DST is set to zero) [here is example](http://ideone.com/OXwiIu)

Comment: @AlirezaMirian: I just updated the title. Hopefully it would be more useful now for someone researching the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Ask if DST is currently in effect.

```
ZoneId
.of( "Europe/Madrid" )
.getRules()
.isDaylightSavings​( Instant.now() )
```

Ask the offset (hours-minutes-seconds) ahead or behind UTC currently in effect.

```
ZoneId
.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
.getRules()
.getOffset​( Instant.now() )
```

## DST comes and goes

To ask "Is Daylight Saving Time in effect?", you *must* specify a moment. The very definition of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is that it comes and goes, twice a year.

Use `Instant` to specify a moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Use `ZoneId` rather than `TimeZone`.

## Offset versus time zone

> TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00");

The string `GMT+1:00` does *not* represent a time zone, it represents an offset. There are many time zones that may all coincidentally be using an offset right now of one hour ahead of UTC, such as `Africa/Casablanca`, `Africa/Brazzaville`, `Africa/Tunis`, `Europe/Andorra`, `Europe/Warsaw`, and many more.

Understand that an offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian. An offset looks like `+05:30` or `-05:00`.

A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. The rules of a time zone are set capriciously by politicians, and change with surprising frequency.

A proper time zone name is composed as `Continent/Region` such as `America/Montreal` or `America/New_York`. See [this list of zones at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (may not be up-to-date).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Gibraltar" ) ;
```

## Asking "Is DST in effect?"

It seems you want to know if DST is currently in effect for a particular time zone. Get the [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) for a particular [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). Then [interrogate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings(java.time.Instant)) for a specific moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Gibraltar" ) ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
boolean dstInEffect = rules.isDaylightSavings​( Instant.now() ) ;
```

And you can ask for the amount of the [offset-from-UTC currently in effect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getOffset(java.time.Instant)). A `ZoneOffset` object represents that number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the prime meridian.

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset​( Instant.now() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).